# variable case insensitive regex match javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to perform a case insensitive regex match for only some of the words in regex string. For example I have this search string:

```
var str = "one two three four five";
```

I'd like to inspect it at least one of the `values` in `/One|TWO/` is present in string. For some values I am interested in **case-sensitive** match, for others in **case-insensitive**. So, for example:

```
str.match(/One|TWO/);
```

Search for `One` should be performed in **case-insensitive** manner, and search for `TWO` should be **case-sensitive**.

Is this variable case sensitive match possible with Javascript Regex engine? Appending `i` as in `str.match(/One|TWO/i);` causes a **case-insensitive** search for the whole regex string and not just parts of it.

Comment: `/[Oo]ne|TWO/` ?

Comment: @bluelovers You should post that as a solution.

Comment: I am providing an example as a way of expressing my problem. In reality, I will know regex search string at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in regex, there are those useful things:

- `(?i)` : starts case-insensitive mode
- `(?-i)` : turns off case-insensitive mode

So, you would be able to write `(?i)One(?-i)TWO`. That will make `One` case-insensitive and `TWO` case-sensitive.

However, they are not supported in JavaScript.

Now, since you said that you will know your `regex` search string at runtime; then, you have two options:

1. Create 2 `regex` search strings, one with `\i` and one without `\i`

```js
var str = "one two three four five";

var insens_re = RegExp("One", "ig");
var sens_re = RegExp("TWO", "g");

console.log(insens_re);
console.log(sens_re);

var a = str.match(insens_re) || [];
var b = str.match(sens_re) || [];

console.log("Matches : ", a.concat(b));
```

2. Use the `function` written below in order to convert any case-insensitive word to a more complex `regex` search string

```js
function makeInsensitive(s) {
    var a = s.toUpperCase().split("");
    var b = s.toLowerCase().split("");

    return a.map((c, i) => "[" + b[i] + c + "]").join("");
}

var str = "one two three four five";

var re = RegExp(makeInsensitive("One") + "|TWO", "g");

console.log(re);
console.log("Matches : ", str.match(re));
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with the first option.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I was of help